# Parse json attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In an intranet app I have HTML elements with custom tags.
There are several types of tags, data-mem is one example.
In the markup it looks like this:

```
<a href="something.html" data-mem='{varname: "value", varname2: "value"}'>Bla Bla</a>
```

What I want to do is get the json attribute and use the name/value pairs in a JS method call. Note: both names and values are unknown and dynamic and I'm using jquery.

```
RegEvent('varname','values','varname2','value');
```

What I have done up till now is get the list of all  tags containing a data-mem attribute:

```
var objs = $('a[data-mem]');
```

I'm a little lost now. Don't really know how to continue.
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extraction part of your problem has been answered well by a few people.  It looks like you are also trying to get an arbitrary conversion from `{a:1, b: 2}` to `RegEvent('a', 1, 'b', 2)`.

To do that, you just need to loop through the arguments of the stored JSON and build an argument array.  Once complete, you can [RegEvent.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass those arguments to the function.

```
$('a[data-mem]').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('mem'),
        args = [];

    $.each(data, function(name, value) {
        args.push(name);
        args.push(value);
    });

    RegEvent.apply(null, args);
});
```

Comment: +1 for `.apply()`. Much neater than my solution. I really need to finish reading (and absorbing) _Javascript: The Good Parts_ by Douglas Crockford...

Comment: Don't take it too seriously.  Some of his bad parts are my favorite parts.

Comment: Changed my mind :) This is a more complete answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery ".data()" method does it automatically.

```
var data = $('#yourId').data('mem');
```

Then "data.varname" will be "value", etc.

*edit* — given your HTML, since you have not given a class or "id" to your `<a>` tag, I guess you could do:

```
var data = $('a[data-mem]').data('mem');
```

It might be better to find a good way to single out the element in question. It depends on the rest of the code of course.

*edit again* — also the JSON has to be valid - property names must be quoted.

Comment: That's because you didn't put an "id" on the element; sorry, I was just giving an example. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is I don't always know what varname is @ code time, so I would not know which props of data to access in this case.

Comment: @3nigma ah OK sorry I didn't notice that the JSON is invalid.  Another update :-)

Answer (score 2):

as @GregL said you have to quote the key to make it a valid JSON and you can pass the function your json and process it inside the function as the key and values are dynamic

```
var data = $("a").data("mem");
RegEvent(data);
```

and inside the function you can loop through the json like

```
$.each(data,function(key,value){
       console.log(key);
console.log(value);
       });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nu3kz/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` to convert the JSON string into an actual JS object.

However, from [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/3BPW7/1), it appears you will need to make sure that the property names are quoted (i.e. `"varname": "value"` instead of `varname: "value"`).

And as @Pointy said, you can then just use the jQuery `.data()` method to retrieve the string.

So your HTML is like this:

```
<a href="something.html" data-mem='{"varname": "value", "varname2": "value"}'>Bla Bla</a>
```

And your Javascript becomes:

```
var data = eval($('a').data('mem'));
// build up an array of properties and values
var prop, valueArray = [], propArray = [];
// iterate over the properties in the object
for (prop in data) {
    // make sure it hasn't come from the prototype chain
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        propArray.push(prop.toString());
        valueArray.push(data[prop]);
    }
}
// now, assuming your function always takes 4 parameters, you can just return the first two pairs of properties and values:
RegEvent(propArray[0], valueArray[0], propArray[1], valueArray[1]);
```

The above example shows how you can use the reflection capabilities of javascript to cater for any property names.

**EDIT:** Updated code to show how to handle any property names.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name or number of properties I will have in the json string, so I wouldn't know which properties to access once I have the object.